# Upload image to Firebase Storage and show as Profile Image

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

I need help with uploading image to Firebase Storage. I have a profile menu in my app. When user tap on this menu he/she can see profile with their info and Profile Image. So I made it so you can select a photo from the gallery. But I need to save photo to Firebase Storage and add ref to Firebase Database by uid. 
In addition, the user may not have a photo, so it will be nill because nothing in Database. Look at photo and you will understand everything

```
extension ProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = editedImage
        self.profileImage.image = selectedImage!
        self.savedImage = selectedImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = originalImage
        self.profileImage.image = selectedImage!
        self.savedImage = selectedImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}



let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView) )
        profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView () {
    print("Tapped")

    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

So, how to upload and dowload image. 
If the user does not have a photo (ref in Database). He will see image from assets. 
If the user have photo he will see image from FB.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzCeG.png)

Comment: Did you look at the Firebase Documentation [Uploading a Picture](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory)? There's also a section of how to download as well. It's fairly straightforward. I don't see any code you've attempted so it's unclear what the issue is. Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Uploading to Firebase storage

```
let imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((self.img_Photo?.image)!, 0.5)!)
let _:NSData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(((self.img_Photo?.image)!))!)
self.uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data: imgData)
```

Function for uploading

```
func uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data:NSData){
    let randomPic = randomString(length: 10)
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Pictures").child("\(value(forKey: "UserUID") ?? randomPic).jpg")
    if data != nil {
        storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                return
            }
            // Fetch the download URL
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                    if(error != nil){
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

                    let urlStr:String = (url?.absoluteString) ?? ""
                    let values = ["photo_url": urlStr]
                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: userID, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            }
        })
    }

}

func registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid:String, values:[String:AnyObject]){
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://domain.firebaseio.com/")
    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)

    usersReference.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.parentVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```